# Disallow URL with specific querystring from crawl using robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, seo, robots.txt, google-crawlers

My client has an ASP.NET MVC web application that also has a WordPress blog in a subfolder.

```
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/wordpress
```

The WordPress site is loaded with some social sharing links that I do not want crawlers to index. For example:

`https://www.example.com/wordpress/some-post/?share=pinterest`

First thing, should there be a `robots.txt` in the `/` folder and also one in the `/wordpress` folder? Or just a single one in the `/` folder? I've tried both without any success.

In my `robots.txt` file I've included the following:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: ?share=pinterest$
```

I've also tried several variations like:

```
Disallow: /wordpress/*/?share=pinterest
```

No matter what rule I have in `robots.txt`, I'm not able to get crawlers to stop trying to index these social sharing links. The plugin that creates these sharing links is also making them "nofollow noindex noreferer", but since they are all internal links it causes issues due to blocking internal "link juice".

How do I form a rule to Disallow crawlers to index any link inside this site that ends with `?share=pinterest`?

Should both sites have a `robots.txt` or only one in the main/root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robots.txt` should **only** be at the root of the domain. `https://example.com/robots.txt` is the correct URL for your `robots.txt` file. Any `robots.txt` file in a subdirectory will be ignored.

By default, `robots.txt` rules are all "starts with" rules. Only a few major bots such as Googlebot support wildcards in `Disallow:` rules. If you use wildcards, the rules will be obeyed by the major search engines but ignored by most less sophisticated bots.

Using `nofollow` on those links isn't really going to effect your internal link juice. Those links are all going to be external redirects that will either pass PageRank out of your site, or if you block that PageRank somehow, it will evaporate. Neither external linking, nor PageRank evaporation hurt the SEO of the rest of your site, so it doesn't really matter from an SEO perspective what you do. You can allow those links to be crawled, use `nofollow` on those links, or disallow those links in `robots.txt`. It won't change how the rest of your site is ranked.

`robots.txt` also has the disadvantage that search engines occasionally index disallowed pages. `robots.txt` blocks crawling, but it doesn't always prevent indexing. If any of those URLs get external links, Google may index the URL with the anchor text of the links it finds to them.

If you really want to hide the social sharing from search engine bots, you should have the functionality handled with `onclick` events. Something like:

```
<a onclick="pintrestShare()">Share on Pinterest</a>
```

Where `pintrestShare` is a JavaScript function that uses `location.href` set the URL of the page to the Pinterest share URL for the current URL.

To directly answer your question about `robots.txt`, this rule is correct:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wordpress/*/?share=pinterest
```

You can use [Google's `robots.txt` testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) to verify that it blocks your URL:

[image]

You have to wait 24 hours after making `robots.txt` changes before bots start obeying the new rules. Bots often cache your old `robots.txt` for a day.

You may have to wait weeks for new results to show in your webmaster tools and search console accounts. Search engines won't report new results until they get around to re-crawling pages, realize the requests are blocked, and that information makes it back to their webmaster information portals.

Comment: Your post answers several questions I had, though my problem seems to have been an invalid robots.txt file. Visual Studio doesn't appear to create compatible files. I ended up opening the published file using FTP and saving it with Notepad (UTF8 with no BOM).